# Android onSharedPreferenceChanged triggered before commit has finished

Tags: android, event-handling, sharedpreferences, commit

I have a very standard `PreferenceFragment` using

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.settings);

    prefs = getPreferenceScreen().getSharedPreferences();
}

 @Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    prefs.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);

    updatePreferences(getPreferenceScreen());
}

@Override
public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences prefs, String key) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onSharedPreferenceChanged " + key);
    updatePreference(findPreference(key));
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    prefs.unregisterOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
}
```

In the settings.xml I reference a `DialogPreference` which looks like this:

```
@Override
protected void onDialogClosed(boolean ok) {
    super.onDialogClosed(ok);

    if (ok) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onDialogClosed OK");

        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
        editor.putString(SettingKeys.SOME_KEY, X);
        final boolean commit = editor.commit();
        Log.d(TAG, "onDialogClosed commit: " + commit);
    }
}
```

However, I get the following sequence:

```
onDialogClosed OK
onSharedPreferenceChanged SOME_KEY
onDialogClosed commit: true
```

which means, the onSharedPreferenceChanged event is triggered before the final commit has finished. This means my `PreferenceFragment` is not able to read the up-to-date value inside the `onSharedPreferenceChanged` handler... which drives me mad.

Any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless I'm missing something, your sequence is actually correct:

1. "onDialogClosed OK" is the first printout
2. Then you're getting your editor, setting some key
3. You are calling editor.commit(). [When a shared preference is changed, added, or removed](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener.html), onShared onSharedPreferenceChanged() is triggered, which then prints your second line: "onSharedPreferenceChanged SOME_KEY".
4. The remaining line gets printed "onDialogClosed commit: true", after the commit

Comment: but the code registering for onSharedPreferenceChanged does not read the up-to-date value, instead it reads pre-commit values

Comment: `findPreference` is just `PreferenceFragment`'s.
`updatePreference` is just doing something along `pref.setSummary((pref.getValue() == null) ? "-" : pref.getEntry())`.
So my code is always reading pre-commmit values...

Comment: It seems PreferenceFragment is always bound to the default SharedPreferences. I rewrote my settings with a singleton-method to always operate on the ApplicationContext's DefaultSharedPreferences. This seems to have fixed my problems. Android's behaviour is really very finicky...